# React Native composite component calling setState of the parent from a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following react-native code. The idea is, I wanted to move all of the common functionality (in the below example, it's the save button and corresponding function into a parent class).

```
export default class DocumentScreen extends Component {
      save() {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            {this.props.children}
            <View>
              <Button onClick={this.save.bind(this)}/>
            </View>
          <View>
        );
      }
    }
```

The children document is responsible for actually defining the fields that appear on the screen, e.g.

```
export default (props) => (
  <DocumentScreen {...props}>
    <View>
     <TextInput onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({val})}/>
    <View>
  </DocumentScreen>
);
```

Unfortunately, `this.setState` called on changes to the text input field does not change the state of the parent object, so when I trigger the `save` function call defined in the `DocumentScreen`, it's state is null.

What's the best way for me to expose the parent's `setState` function in the child component?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I see you have use HOC as the answer, I think can make use of renderProps. This will be better than using HOC. You get more freedom and also you don't gonna have props naming problem. A good video where you can see the strength of it vs HOC https://youtu.be/BcVAq3YFiuc

Little example

```
class DocumentScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  }

  save() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleChange = value => {
    this.setState({ value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.props.children({ handleChange: this.handleChange })}
        <View>
          <Button onClick={this.save.bind(this)}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Input = (props) => (
  <DocumentScreen {...props}>
    {({ handleChange }) => (
      <View>
        <TextInput onChangeText={handleChange}/>
      <View>
    )}
  </DocumentScreen>
);
```

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common use case with React. The solution should be declare the handler function inside the parent component then pass it to the children. You will need to pay attention to context of the function so the `this` is correctly pointed to the parent function, it can be done by either use `bind` function in javascript or declare the event handler using arrow function. An example is as below:

```
export default class DocumentScreen extends Component {
      changeHandler = (val) => {
        this.setState({ val });
      }

      // Binding function inside JSX should be avoid
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
             {this.props.children}
             <ChildComponent onChange={this.changeHandler} />
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

// Child Component

export default (props) => (
  <DocumentScreen>
    <View>
     <TextInput onChangeText={props.onChange}/>
    </View>
  </DocumentScreen>
);
```

Comment: I am including my child components like this `{this.props.children}`, there is no `ChildComponent` class being imported into the parent to which I can pass props.

Comment: From a React application design point of view, it's probably not a good approach, as you don't want an arbitrary children to access and mutate a parent state. If you still want to go this way, you might want to look at the new React.Context api. Another approach, which is recommended by React itself to solve this kind of problem is to `lifting the state up`, which mean to move the state up to nearest common parent of both components. Otherwise, you can look into using a state management library like Redux. However, all of these approach are overkilled and overcomplicated to your problem.

Comment: thanks, I've used your suggestion but ended up having to wrap things in a HOC (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

So, what I ended up doing was wrapping my parent component in a HOC function, like this:

```
export function wrapper(DocumentComponent) {
  return class extends Component {

    changeHandler = (val) => {
      this.setState({ val });
    }

    save() {
      console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <DocumentComponent onChange={this.changeHanlder}/>
          <View>
            <Button onClick={this.save.bind(this)}/>
          </View>
        <View>
      );
    }

  };    
}
```

And then I've used the wrapper function to pass the child to the parent (and the parent can now pass the props back to the child).

```
export default wrapper(
  (props) => (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={props.onChange}/>
    </View>
  )
)
```

There is a bit of circular referencing happening here though...